# Solving a prediction problem where datasets are time based?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, pattern-recognition

How would one go about solving a machine learning problem where the datasets are time based but not necessarily the data?

Say for example in an undergraduate degree. Each year a new batch of students come in, they spend 4 years and then graduate with a class. So a single dataset would consist of data of a single batch (those who enrolled in one particular year) spanning 4 years. And we have many such datasets, equaling to the number of batches of the undergraduate program( those who  enrolled in 2015,2016, ... etc).

The problem is to predict the graduating class for the new batch of students, when they first enter the university, using background data, and improve on the prediction as they continue with their degree. The patterns identified for each batch (dataset), may or may not be unique to that batch. What needs to be done is that, for each dataset, patterns can be identified and those patterns that are consistent through time (batches) can be used for prediction of the new batch.

The conventional time series analysis does not seem directly applicable here. Any help or guidance in the correct path is appreciated.

Comment: You are just saying _" So a single dataset would consist of data of a single batch  "_ . What is your actual data?

Comment: For each student of that batch(intake), those would contain data such as high school GPA, Gender, Area of residence, Grades of subjects done in college in each year and finally the class with he/she graduates as the output